ESP32 not entering deep sleep mode despite deep sleep function being called (RTOS)
I am working on a project using an ESP32, where I need the device to enter deep sleep mode for 5 minutes when a button is pressed in the Blynk app (connected to virtual pin V5). I have added the necessary code to put the ESP32 into deep sleep mode, but it seems like the device is not actually entering deep sleep as it continues executing other functions.Here is the relevant part of my code:
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID "TMPL6pV_GZrck"
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME "Pow"
#define BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN "RsljOwPnzkrvogRxzNUfKWrWDrCFMMpZ"

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp32.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"

// WiFi Credentials
#define WIFI_SSID "Gala"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "12345678"

// DHT Sensor Settings
#define DHTPIN 26
#define DHTTYPE DHT22

// GPS Configuration
HardwareSerial neogps(2);

// Pin Definitions
const int alertPin = 23;

// Global Instance Declaration
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// Function Declarations
void setup();
void loop();
void Task1code(void * pvParameters);
void Task2code(void * pvParameters);
void connectToWiFi();
void sendDataAll();
void gpsAll(float &longitude, float &latitude, float &speedKmph);
void readDHTSensor(float &temperature, float &humidity);
void sendDataToThingSpeak(float latitude, float longitude, float speed, float temperature, float humidity);
void handleBlynkV2(int pinValue);
void handleBlynkV5(int pinValue);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(alertPin, OUTPUT);
    Serial.println("DHT22 Temperature and Humidity Reading");
    dht.begin();
    neogps.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, 19, 21); // GPS Serial Port
    connectToWiFi();
    Blynk.begin(BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN, WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);

    // Task Creation
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(Task1code, "Task1", 10000, NULL, 1, NULL, 1);
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(Task2code, "Task2", 10000, NULL, 1, NULL, 0);
}

void loop() {
    // Intentionally Empty
}

void Task1code(void * pvParameters) {
    for (;;) {
        sendDataAll();
        delay(1000);
    }
}

void Task2code(void * pvParameters) {
    for (;;) {
        Blynk.run();
        delay(100);
    }
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V2) {
    handleBlynkV2(param.asInt());
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V5) {
    handleBlynkV5(param.asInt());
}

void handleBlynkV2(int pinValue) {
    if (pinValue == 1) {
        digitalWrite(alertPin, HIGH);
        Serial.println("On");
    } else {
        digitalWrite(alertPin, LOW);
        Serial.println("Down");
    }
}

void handleBlynkV5(int pinValue) {
    if (pinValue == 1) {
        Serial.println("Entering deep sleep for 5 minutes...");
        esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(5 * 60 * 1000000); // 5 minutes in microseconds
        esp_deep_sleep_start();
    }
}

void connectToWiFi() {
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println("Connecting...");
    }
    Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
}

void sendDataAll() {
    float temperature, humidity, longitude, latitude, speedKmph;
    readDHTSensor(temperature, humidity);
    gpsAll(longitude, latitude, speedKmph);
    sendDataToThingSpeak(latitude, longitude, speedKmph, temperature, humidity);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V0, temperature);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V1, humidity);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V3, speedKmph);
}

void gpsAll(float &longitude, float &latitude, float &speedKmph) {
    bool newData = false;
    for (unsigned long start = millis(); millis() - start < 1000;) {
        while (neogps.available()) {
            if (gps.encode(neogps.read())) {
                newData = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (newData && gps.location.isValid()) {
        longitude = gps.location.lng();
        latitude = gps.location.lat();
        speedKmph = gps.speed.kmph();
        Serial.print("Latitude: ");
        Serial.println(latitude, 6);
        Serial.print("Longitude: ");
        Serial.println(longitude, 6);
        Serial.print("Speed: ");
        Serial.println(speedKmph);
    } else {
        Serial.println("No valid or new GPS data");
    }
}

void readDHTSensor(float &temperature, float &humidity) {
    temperature = dht.readTemperature();
    humidity = dht.readHumidity();
    if (isnan(temperature) || isnan(humidity)) {
        Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
    } else {
        Serial.print("Temperature: ");
        Serial.print(temperature);
        Serial.println(" °C");
        Serial.print("Humidity: ");
        Serial.print(humidity);
        Serial.println(" %");
    }
}

void sendDataToThingSpeak(float latitude, float longitude, float speed, float temperature, float humidity) {
    HTTPClient http;
    String apiKey = "TJC7WXME422QXQSX"; // ThingSpeak API Key
    String url = "https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=" + apiKey
                 + "&field1=" + String(latitude, 6) + "&field2=" + String(longitude, 6)
                 + "&field3=" + String(temperature) + "&field4=" + String(humidity)
                 + "&field5=" + String(speed);
    http.begin(url);
    int httpResponseCode = http.GET();
    if (httpResponseCode == 200) {
        Serial.println("Data sent successfully to ThingSpeak");
    } else {
        Serial.print("Error sending data to ThingSpeak. HTTP error code: ");
        Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    }
    http.end();
}


When I press the button on the Blynk app, the serial monitor displays "Entering deep sleep for 5 minutes...", but the ESP32 continues to execute other tasks and does not actually go into deep sleep. What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that the ESP32 enters deep sleep mode as intended?
I'm using an ESP32-WROOM., but it seems like it's not working in my case.The tasks continue to run, and the device does not enter deep sleep mode.
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
